# ajax "delete" method working in local but not in remote site [laravel]

Tags: laravel-4, kendo-grid, delete-method

I have a Kendo Ui grid in my laravel application. It uses laravel resource route for CRUD operation. Everything on kendo grid (read,create,update,destroy) works fine when the grid is accessed from localhost. But when i try from remote address (network connected pc) then "grid destroy" does not work with "delete" method.'get' and 'post' method works fine from remote address. The "delete" method request takes almost 4-5 sec to send the request to laravel ,moreover the request does not have any Form Data ( Input::all() = empty array ). Strange thing is it works fine in localhost. I have searched for google,laravel doc, kendo ui doc but no lack. Please help.

Comment: Think this is CORS problem, google on that :)

Comment: Have you checked on the remote server that the DELETE verb is an allowed HTTP verb. This may have been blocked/disabled by default.

Comment: @DavidShorthose i am using the same local server for both requests.

Comment: this is strange behavior, show your route and your corresponding delete method

Comment: @Touhid have you tried to run fiddler to see what is happening when the request is being fired? This is why I thought it may be a VERB issue if POST and GET were working for you remotely.